# What triggers a Retry when using a Copy data activity whose source is a REST service

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that includes a Copy data activity whose source is a REST service. The service sometimes times out - about 1 out of 10 times. I would like to have the activity retry the call but I don't know what triggers a retry. Does the service just need to return a 'success' key with a value of 'false'?

How does this affect the pagination rules? Does the activity start over from the first page? or does the activity use the current QueryParameter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Retry' and 'Retry Interval' parameters are properties of the Activity object and have nothing to do with other properties of the given activity, like the source property as referenced by my question. In this case, my source was returning a failure and the activity would retry up to the number specified by the 'Retry' parameter. In my case, I had the Retry parameter set to 1 and when I drilled down to the activity under the Monitor tab, I saw the activity retry after the Retry Interval.

The Pagination Rules have nothing to do with the Retry; pagination is a function of the REST service. When the activity fails, the Retry function will effectively start over from the 1st page.

Comment: Thanks for this, @sartoris. If I were to link my failing activity to another activity to be executed in case of failure, will it get executed after every retry?

Comment: that's a good question! I would assume not. I suggest testing it out on a service that fails every other time (or randomly 50% of the time). Maybe create an Azure Function App?